# Is there any transposition available in between QGA and other openings?

Tags: opening, queens-gambit-accepted, closed-position, transpositions

I'm a chess player with ELO 1600. Now I'm trying to learn transpositions in chess. QGA is my favorite opening as white. But most of the time black chooses Queen's Gambit Declined. So now I'm trying to get to get QGA by transposition. Chess is all about positions. But I just want to know:

**Are there any transpositions available in between QGA and other openings?**

Comment: I think it's difficult for *white* to transpose into the QGA, but *black* has several opportunities to transpose in or out of the opening. Let me know if you are interested in such transpositions.

Comment: Please tell me transposition for black also...

Comment: Unfortunately, only Black can choose to transpose into such lines, and from what I remember they might not be 100% same as the mainlines. Your best bet may be `1.c4 c6 2.e4! d5 3.cxd5 cxd5 4.exd5 Qxd5 ( ...Nxd5 is another story, again we see Black having a choice here )  5.Nc3 Qd8` with the transposition to the mainlines as far as I recall...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One transposition white can try is from the French Exchange variation (if you know your opponent plays the French).

```
[FEN ""]

1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5 3. exd5 exd5 4. c4 dxc4 (4... Nf6) 5. Bxc4
```

It transposes to the variation `1. d4 d5 2. c4 dxc4 3. e3 e5 4. Bxc4 exd4 5. exd4` from [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5627/best-continuation-for-this-counter-to-queens-gambit-accepted).

In the French move order, clever black players won't take the pawn on `c4` already on move 4, but will wait until white plays `Be2`. If white then later regains a pawn with `Bxc4`, the bishop will have lost a tempo.