# Are there decided recent games with 1. b4 at top level?

Tags: opening, famous-players

I would like to have a survey of the decided games with 1.b4 since 2010,
 where both players had at least 2600 Elo.

chessgames.com allows to search games with given moves (with tight limits), but 
 does not allow to search for Elo.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: I doubt any sane GM would play such an opening, due to reasons I covered in my answer to [this](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/6474/how-to-play-against-the-polish-opening/6482#6482) question. I strongly advise you to take a good look at it. Best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only games I could find meeting your criteria are

- Ivanchuk - Giri, Leon Masters (rapid) 2013
- Short - Caruana, London Classic (rapid) 2013

Comment: Such non-book moves are usually found in blitz and rapid only.

Answer (score 0):

I found two games since 2010 by players > 2600.

One in 2018, and one in 2013.

One reply by black was d5 the other e5.

Black had the overwhelming win ratio for all of the ones with that opening.